# Spring BeanPropertyBindingResult error on image field

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

This seems to be an easy issue but I can find the solution..
I’m building a spring app with thymeleaf and using postgres as my db, I have a form that will allow the users to enter a book information with image but I’m getting an error since I’ve added an image field in my book class, here is my files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
       <version>3.1.1</version>
       <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>book-store</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>book-store</name>
    <description>book-store</description>
    <properties>
       <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
          <scope>runtime</scope>
          <optional>true</optional>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
          <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
          <scope>runtime</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
          <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
          <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>9.21.1</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
          <version>1.4</version>
       </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
       <plugins>
          <plugin>
             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          </plugin>
       </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

```
# Datasource configuration
spring.datasource.url=${datasourceUrl}
spring.datasource.username=${datasourceUsername}
spring.datasource.password=${datasourcePassword}
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

logging.file.path=${logDir}

# Flyway configuration
spring.flyway.enabled=true
spring.flyway.baseline-on-migrate=true
spring.flyway.locations=classpath:db/migration

# Multipart configuration
# Maximum file size for each request in bytes
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=10MB

# Maximum size allowed for multipart/form-data request
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=10MB
```

```
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Min;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank;

@Entity
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    private String title;

    @NotBlank
    private String author;

    private String publisher;

    @Min(1900)
    private int year;

    private double price;

    @Lob
    @Column(columnDefinition = "bytea")
    private byte[] imageData;

    public Book() {}

    public Book(String title, String author, String publisher, int year, double price, byte[] imageData) {
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        this.publisher = publisher;
        this.year = year;
        this.price = price;
        this.imageData = imageData;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public String getPublisher() {
        return publisher;
    }

    public void setPublisher(String published) {
        this.publisher = published;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public byte[] getImageData() {
        return imageData;
    }

    public void setImageData(byte[] imageData) {
        this.imageData = imageData;
    }

}
```

```
import com.example.bookstore.persistense.model.Book;
import com.example.bookstore.service.IBookService;
import jakarta.validation.Valid;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.Year;
import java.util.List;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/books")
public class BookController {

    public static final String REDIRECT_BOOKS = "redirect:/api/v1/books";
    private static final Logger LOGGER = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(BookController.class);
    private final IBookService bookService;
    int currentYear = Year.now().getValue();

    public BookController(IBookService bookService) {
        this.bookService = bookService;
    }

    @PostMapping("/save")
    public String saveBook(@Valid Book book, BindingResult bindingResult, @RequestParam("imageData") MultipartFile imageData) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "add";
        }
        if (!imageData.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                byte[] imageDataBytes = imageData.getBytes();
                book.setImageData(imageDataBytes);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "Failed to process image upload.", e);
            }
        }
        bookService.save(book);
        return REDIRECT_BOOKS;
    }
//other methods

}
```

```
<head xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <th:block th:insert="~{fragments/headerFragment.html}" />
</head>
<body>
<head th:insert="~{fragments/navbarFragment.html}"></head>
<main th:with="baseUrl=@{/api/v1/books}" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="mx-auto col-10 col-md-8 col-lg-6">
            <h1>Add New book</h1>

            <form method="post" th:action="${baseUrl + '/save'}" th:object="${book}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label class="form-label" for="titleInput">Title</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="titleInput" th:field="*{title}" type="text" required>
                </div>

                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label class="form-label" for="authorInput">Author</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="authorInput" th:field="*{author}" type="text" required>
                </div>

                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label class="form-label" for="publisherInput">Publisher</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="publisherInput" th:field="*{publisher}" type="text">
                </div>

                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label class="form-label" for="yearInput">Year</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="yearInput" min="1900" step="1" th:field="*{year}" th:max="${currentYear}"
                           type="number" required>
                </div>

                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label class="form-label" for="priceInput">Price</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="priceInput" min="2" step="0.1" th:field="*{price}" type="number" required>
                </div>

                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label class="form-label" for="bookCoverInput">Book Cover</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="bookCoverInput" th:field="*{imageData}" type="file" accept="image/png, image/jpeg">
                </div>

                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
</body>
```

When I submit the form I get this error:

```
org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'book' on field 'imageData': rejected value [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile@1e484afe]; codes [typeMismatch.book.imageData,typeMismatch.imageData,typeMismatch.[B,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [book.imageData,imageData]; arguments []; default message [imageData]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile' to required type 'byte[]' for property 'imageData'; Cannot convert value of type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile' to required type 'byte' for property 'imageData[0]': PropertyEditor [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomNumberEditor] returned inappropriate value of type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile']
```

the error is returned in bindingResult when i try so save the book in the database.

Thanks in advance.

When I submit the the form the data should be persisted in the database, but the bindingResult retrun some errors.

Comment: Because a `byte[]` is not a `MultipartFile` which is what the parameter actually is. Submit it under a different name so that Spring will not try to bind it.